# Why does the scrollbar revert to original position?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to write a program that scrolls a DI bitmap area in a modeless dialog. So far the code has created two scrollbar controls; one horizontal and one vertical. The problem is the scroll box is not staying in the last position when you move it, but reverts back to the start position. Here is some of the code.

```
  //Create a vertical scroll.
  tmphndwindow2 = CreateWindowA(WC_SCROLLBAR, \
                  NULL, \
                  WS_CHILD | \
                  WS_VISIBLE | \
                  SBS_VERT,
                  409, \
                  100, \
                  16, \
                  500, \
                  tmphndwindow, \
                  (HMENU)5, \
                  GLB_HInstance, \
                  NULL);

  //Set the scroll range
  SetScrollRange(tmphndwindow2, \
                 SB_VERT, \
                 0, \
                 500, \
                 TRUE);

  //Create a horizontal scroll.
  tmphndwindow2 = CreateWindowA(WC_SCROLLBAR, \
                                NULL, \
                                WS_CHILD | \
                                WS_VISIBLE | \
                                SBS_HORZ,
                                8, \
                                601, \
                                400, \
                                16, \
                                tmphndwindow, \
                                (HMENU)6, \
                                GLB_HInstance, \
                                NULL);

  //Set the scroll range
  SetScrollRange(tmphndwindow2, \
                 SB_HORZ, \
                 0, \
                 400, \
                 TRUE);
```

In the code above, tmphndwindow is the dialog.

I have written code to handle the WM_HSCROLL message:

```
 //Handle the WM_HSCROLL message.
 if(tmpmsg == WM_HSCROLL){

  //Get the type of horizontal scroll.
  tmpn = (tmpwparam & 0xFFFF);

  //Check if the user scrolled one unit
  //to the right.
  if(tmpn == SB_LINERIGHT){

   //Add one to the tmphscroll variable.
   tmphscroll = (tmphscroll + 1);

  } //EndIf

  //Check if the user scrolled one unit
  //to the left.
  if(tmpn == SB_LINELEFT){

   //Subtract one from the tmphscroll
   //variable.
   tmphscroll = (tmphscroll - 1);

  } //EndIf

  //Check if the user is scrolling either
  //to the right or to the left.
  if(tmpn == SB_THUMBTRACK){

   //Set the tmphscroll variable.
   tmphscroll = (tmpwparam >> 16);

  } //EndIf

  //Search for the horizontal scroll
  //control.
  tmphndwindow2 = GetDlgItem(GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
                             6);

  //Set some members of the tmpscrollinfo
  //object.
  tmpscrollinfo.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
  tmpscrollinfo.fMask = SIF_POS;
  tmpscrollinfo.nPos = tmphscroll;

  //Set the position of the scroll box.
  SetScrollInfo(tmphndwindow2, \
                SB_HORZ, \
                &tmpscrollinfo, \
                TRUE);

  //Returns
  return FALSE;
```

Comment: Why do you escape all line ends in the function calls? This is very unusual.

Comment: I find it easier to read that way. Especially when the function has a lot of arguments.

Comment: I didn't mean multiple lines, I was asking why  you escape them with the backslashes.

Comment: I always thought that the compiler will report an error if the newline is not escaped but I just rebuilt the program without the backslash and it worked. I learnt something new today. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `SB_CTL` instead of `SB_HORZ` in your call to `SetScrollInfo`.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, the SB_CTL fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jonathan Potter. You need to use `SB_CTL` instead of `SB_HORZ` in your call to `SetScrollInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also handle SB_THUMBPOSITION.

As the user drags the thumb box, the window procedure will receive a series of SB_THUMBTRACK notifications, which you are handling.  When the user releases the mouse button, there's an additional SB_THUMBPOSITION notification that includes the final position.  This is usually redundant with the last SB_THUMBTRACK message, so it'll seem like it works.

But live drag scrolling wasn't always available.  In older versions of Windows, users could disable features like that, which they might want to do if they had a slow machine.  In those cases, there would be no SB_THUMBTRACK messages, so the SB_THUMBPOSITION message was not redundant, but essential.